# On $BPP$ in $P^{NP}$ and $SETH$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds, big-picture, derandomization, pseudorandom-generators

It is believed showing $BPP$ in $P$ involves good $PRG$s and faces lower bound barriers.

1. Does showing $BPP$ in $P^{NP}$ which would mean $BPP\neq EXP^{NP}$ face similar $PRG$ and give lower bounds?
2. Does $BPP$ in $P^{NP}$ and $SAT$ is in $2^{n}/f(n)$ at a superpolynomial $f(n)$ give anything for $BPP$ other than $BPP\neq NEXP$ ($NEXP\not\subseteq P/poly$ would hold)?
3. $BPP\neq EXP^{NP}$ and $BPP\neq NEXP$ mean $BPP\neq EXP^{NP}\cup NEXP$. What does this mean for lower bounds?
4. How far would we be away from $BPP\neq EXP$? Does this truly need good $PRG$s if $BPP\neq EXP^{NP}\cup NEXP$ is achieved without constructing good $PRG$s?

Comment: I think that by "derandomizing to P^NP" the OP means showing that BPP is in P^NP.